# Is the evaluation of static member function during construction before base initialization undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

I am wondering if this exemple evokes undefined behavior:

```
struct Base
  {
  Base(int);
  };
struct Derived
  :Base
  {
  static int a_static_function();

  Derived()
    :Base(a_static_function())//is it undefined behavior?
    {}
  };
```

EDIT: I am asking that because of this paragraph in the C++ standard [class.base.init]:

> Member functions (including virtual member functions, 13.3) can be called for an object under construction.
>   Similarly, an object under construction can be the operand of the typeid operator (8.2.8) or of a dynamic_-
>   cast (8.2.7). However, if these operations are performed in a ctor-initializer (or in a function called directly
>   or indirectly from a ctor-initializer) before all the mem-initializers for base classes have completed, the
>   program has undefined behavior.

It does not seems to be specific to non-static member functions.

Comment: Why do you think it would be?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Indeed, this is because of a sentence in the standard... I add it

Comment: IMO it is just an oversight in the standard and the intent was to talk about non-static member functions here

Comment: @M.M. I understand know what means oversight: focusing on a small part of the c++ standard leads to miss-interpretation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not UB.

A static member function is like an ordinary (non-member) function, except that it has access to `private` stuff (e.g.private static data, and other static member function).

My understanding of your citation of the standard is that it applies for non-static member functions.

Comment: Can't it access _any_ `static` class function and field, not just those declared as `private`?

Comment: It also has access to all non static data, it just needs an instance of the class to get them.